# Function declarations or expressions for class methods?

Tags: methods, typescript, function-declaration

A coworker of mine and I have had this discussion several times. There are two ways to define class methods. The first way is with a function *declaration*:

```
class Action {
    public execute(): void {
        this.doSomething();
    }
    ...
}
```

Function declarations tend to be easier to read. Only one function object is used for each instance of `Action`, so they're also more memory-friendly.

The second is with a function *expression*:

```
class Action {
    public execute: () => void = () => {
        this.doSomething();
    };
    ...
}
```

Function expressions need more typing (especially with type definitions), are harder to read, and generate a new function object for every instance of `Action`. And if you're generating lots and lots of objects, that's bad.

However, function expressions have one small benefit: they preserve the context of `this` (i.e. the `Action` instance) no matter who calls them:

```
var instance = new Action();
setTimeout(instance.execute);
```

A method declared as a function expression works as expected in this case. Function declarations fail miserably, but they can easily be fixed by doing this instead:

```
var instance = new Action();

setTimeout(() => instance.execute());
// or
setTimeout(instance.execute.bind(instance));
```

So, is one considered better practice over the other, or is this purely situational/preferential?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In my opinion, arrow functions should be used as class methods only when you know for sure that the function might be called with a different context for `this` (if it's passed as an event handler, for example) and you prefer to avoid using [Function.prototype.bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind).

There are several reasons for that, including, as you wrote, for code readability, but the main reason is for inheritance.
If you use an arrow function then you simply assign a function to the instance as a member, but the function won't be added to the prototype:

```
// ts
class A {
    fn1() {}

    fn2 = () => {}
}

// js
var A = (function () {
    function A() {
        this.fn2 = function () { };
    }
    A.prototype.fn1 = function () { };
    return A;
}());
```

So what happens if you want to extend this class and override the `fn2` method?
Because it's a property and not part of the prototype, you'll need to do something like:

```
class B extends A {
    private oldFn2 = this.fn2;

    fn2 = () => {
        this.fn2();
    }
}
```

Which just looks terrible when compared to:

```
class A {
    fn1() {}

    fn2() {}
}

class B extends A {
    fn2() {
        super.fn2();
    }
}
```

---

There are a few reasons to prefer using the `bind` method over an anonymous function. I find it to be more implicit, because it's the **exact** same function but bound to a specific `this`. On the other hand, in the anonymous function, you can add more code other than calling the actual function.

Another thing is that the `bind` function lets you not only bind which object will be considered as `this`, but also to bind parameters:

```
function fn(one, two, three) {}
fn.bind(null, 1, 2)(3);
fn(1, 2, 3);
```

The two invocations of `fn` here are the same.
You can do that with an anonymous functions, but not always:

```
var a = ["zero", "one", "two", "three", "four", "five"];
function fn(value, index) {
    console.log(value, index);
}

// works
a.forEach((item, index) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
        fn(item, index);
    }, 45);
});

// works
for (let i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    setTimeout(() => {
        fn(a[i], i);
    }, 45);
}

// doesn't work as i is undefined when the function is invoked
for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    setTimeout(() => {
        fn(a[i], i);
    }, 45);
}

// works because the value of i and the value of a[i] are bound
for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    setTimeout(fn.bind(null, a[i], i), 45);
}
```

Comment: Excellent. I hadn't even considered inheritance/prototype scenarios. Even if a method might be used as an event handler, I would think most situations could be mitigated using the anonymous function wrapper as described above.

Comment: @Craxal I prefer using the `bind` function instead of an anonymous one, but yes in either case it's not much of a hustle.

Comment: Are there any benefits to preferring `bind`? I suppose you wouldn't have to worry about explicitly handling and passing arguments, for one.